# Property children is optional for no reason

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-generics

I have a function called `provide` that wraps a component with an array of providers.
The syntax is `provide([Provider,propsObject])(WrapedComponent)` and it replaces:

```js
<Provider {...propsObject}>
    <WrapedComponent/>
</Provider>
```

My types are provider and providers, and they are used in `wrap` and `provide`:

```js
//This type is Component or tuple of [Component,props without children]
type Provider<P> = React.ComponentType<P>  | [React.ComponentType<P>, Omit<P, "children">]; 

type Providers<T extends any[]> = {
  [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends T[number] ? Provider<T[P]> : never;
};
```

The wrap :

```js
const wrap = <T extends any[]>(...providers: Providers<T>) => ( element: React.ReactNode) =>
  providers.reduceRight((element: React.ReactNode, provider) => {
    let Provider: React.ComponentType<any>,
      providerProps: object = {};

    if (Array.isArray(provider)) [Provider, providerProps] = provider;
    else Provider = provider!;

    const wrap = createElement(Provider, providerProps, element);

    return wrap;
  }, element);
```

And the provide function is:

```js
const provide = <T extends any[]>(...providers: Providers<T>) => 
<P extends { children: React.ReactNode }>(  component: React.ComponentType<P>) => {
  const Provide: React.FC<P> = (props) => {
    return wrap(...providers)(
      createElement(component, props)
    ) as React.ReactElement<P>;
  };
  return Provide;
};
```

**All this code used to work, and works in most places.** But I have one place that isn't working and I don't get why.
The error is:
[image]

The bottom line is that the wrapping components thinks that the `provide` function returns `children` as optional prop, and that's not true. How do I fix it?

Comment: Because you're using `React.ComponentType` and not all React components require children, so it's optional. Which means you can't use it for a type where children is required. Use a custom type that makes children non-optional: `{ children: React.ReactNode }` (note the lack of optionality).

Comment: @JaredSmith Its still not working

Comment: Did you also replace `React.FC<P>` which has the same issue? Basically, any of the regular React types are going to mark `children` optional. If you want it to be required, you have to make it so.

Comment: But how can I fix this without marking `children` as optional in my components (even when children are required)? I tried to change the type of Props (to do somthing like `<P extends {children:ReactNode}`) and still had a problem

Comment: And why is it breaking in specific configuration? This code is running on SandBox and on multiple other projects without any problem, and it started crashing on one specific project.

Comment: Please create a minimal reproduceable example. I cannot replicate your setup with no more than you've posted. In particular please post the definitions of your arguments (or stripped-down definitions that produce the error) to `provide`.

Comment: Created a repo - https://github.com/ReutSchremer/ts-error
Thanks so much

Comment: That's cool and I'm looking at it now, but please do try to include it in the actual question, links go dead, resources get moved, etc.

Comment: Ummm.... the repo runs fine for me? I'm not getting any errors at either compile or run time.

Comment: It runs the app (localhost works) but in the console it still shows 'fail to compile, TS error'

Comment: Ok I see it. I'll work on an answer, but its weird if there's a compile error it shouldn't even be running

Comment: Hi @JaredSmith , did you figure it out?

Comment: I have not yet. I'm moving across my country next week and have been too busy with a combination of work and life. I did work on it a little though, and I can tell you the 3-4 "obvious" things I tried did not work, and I was surprised.